# Which is correct or what are the defferences between: 'use of a something , 'using of something' or just 'using something'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-requests

I've run into a phrase: 'use of PPE (personal protective equipment)'. But I'm confused with the 'use'- forms as a noun. Is it correct to say 'using of PPE' or 'using PPE' without a preposition? And what's the difference between 'use' and 'using' as nouns?

Comment: Let's see the whole sentence, please. *Using of* sounds wrong.

Comment: PPE is worn, not used, usually.

Comment: I'd usually go either with "use of sth" or "using sth". "Doing of sth" sounds awkward, even though I would find it every now and then in some technical specifications. (Though I wouldn't guarantee their linguistic accuracy). However, "making of..." always bugged me. To answer your question - in the example given I can see no significant difference.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for answering my question! 
@YosefBaskin Actually, it's not a whole sentence. It's just a short comment to a table column 'Existing Control Mesures'.

Comment: @Lambie, You're right, 'wear' is also suitable. But what would be correct: 'wearing PPE' or 'wearing of PPE'?

Comment: @JulesCocovin, I got it. I've found some information about the gerund + 'of'-preposition: 'In a few cases, using the gerund + of is correct when it is important to emphasize the specific act the gerund describes. It also sounds extremely formal to an English speaker; it is not a construction one would use in everyday speech except as a joke.' So, in accordance with my example  'use of PPE' and 'using PPE' are both correct, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, what you found is right: The carrying of unregistered firearms is forbidden. = Carrying unregistered firearms is forbidden. The first might be how the law, for example, is written.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks!